# Expression builder - Counting tick boxing if TRUE

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am using the following expression but it does not work, any ideas on where I am going wrong?

```
=DCount("[lateness]","[tblsick]","[Latesness] = -1")
```

- I have a table called tblsick
- I have colums called lateness, which are tick boxes

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I had a spelling mistake - Works fine now, doh!